# Can someone explain why $\| \cdot \|_p, p = \frac{1}{2}$ isn't a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

$\| \cdot \|_p, p = \frac{1}{2}$ or "half norm" is not a norm

What is a quick way to verify that it is indeed not a norm?

Comment: Does it fulfill the triangle inequality? / Is the unit ball for such a "norm" a convex set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ball of unity that is induced by the "norm" is not convex. The points $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ are in the Ball, but their midpoint isn't.

This can be visualized in [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28|x|%29+%2B+sqrt%28|y|%29+%3C%3D+1).